# SQL function to generate new row per event?

Tags: sql, string, csv, split, vertica

I've looked for an answer here to no avail; wondering if this problem is best suited outside SQL environment but thought I'd see how it could be solved.

I'm trying to look at web journeys and as a result need my data to be in the following format:

```
ID      DATE       EVENT
1       01/01/20   "Landing Page"
1       01/01/20   "purchase page"
2...etc
```

At present the data is in the following format:

```
ID       DATE       EVENT
1        01/01/20   "Landing page","purchase page"
2... etc
```

I essentially want to break out the event field by comma and create a new row for each comma separated event with all other fields duplicated. My SQL isn't great, have tried numerous temp tables, unions and split_parts to break out the field to some success but cannot get it into its own row.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, postgresql, sql-server...?

Comment: Thanks, its VerticaSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it works as @GMB suggested.

Only that the function `StringTokenizerDelim()` is not in the default search path.

You'll have to qualify it explicitly with the `v_txtindex` schema in which it resides:

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(id,dt,ev) AS (
          SELECT 1, DATE '2020-01-01','landing page,purchase page'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2020-01-02','landingpage,browse-article page,purchase page'
)
,
tokens AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , dt
  , v_txtindex.StringTokenizerDelim(ev,',') OVER(PARTITION BY id,dt)
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  id
, dt
, words AS event
FROM tokens;
-- out  id |     dt     |        event        
-- out ----+------------+---------------------
-- out   1 | 2020-01-01 | landing page
-- out   1 | 2020-01-01 | purchase page
-- out   2 | 2020-01-02 | landingpage
-- out   2 | 2020-01-02 | browse-article page
-- out   2 | 2020-01-02 | purchase page
```

Answer (score 3):

Vertica offers [tokenizer function `StringTokenizerDelim`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Tables/TextSearch/PreconfiguredTokenizers.htm) for this purpose, as part of the text search package:

```
select id, date, words as event
from (
    select id, date, StringTokenizerDelim(event, ',') over (partition by id)
    from mytable
) t
```